# Module '"pdfjs-dist"' has no exported member 'Viewport'.ts(2305)

Tags: typescript

I am trying to import viewport from pdfjs-dist in react, I installed the `"pdfjs-dist": "^3.11.174"`, then tried to import the viewport like this:

```
import { PDFDocumentProxy, PDFPageProxy, Viewport } from 'pdfjs-dist';
```

but show me this error `Module '"pdfjs-dist"' has no exported member 'Viewport'.ts(2305)`. I have tried to install the `@types/pdfjs-dist` but told me the lib is deprecated. what should I do to import the viewport? I also tried to using the `@types/react-pdf` but also told me the lib is deprecated.